# mysql database cannot connect to Java Spring Boot

Tags: mysql, spring

I'm trying my first Spring Boot application. And when I try to connect my sql database, it shows the application failed to connect to the database.

Here's the error message:

```
Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class


Action:

Consider the following:
    If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
    If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).
```

my yml file:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    # type: com.alibaba.druid.pool.DruidDataSource
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    url: jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/test?useSSL=false
    username: root
    password: 
    #testWhileIdle: true
    #validationQuery: SELECT 1
  #jpa:
    #database: mysql
    #database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
```

my pom.xml file:

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- myBatis -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mybatis.spring.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.28</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- junit test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- lombok dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/java</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.xml</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.3</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Anyone knows why?

Thanks!!

I tried to edit my paplication.yml file and change datasource property, but it does't work.

Comment: Hi there, what IDE are you using? And did you make DB connection in IDE? Usually when you connect to Datasource with IDE is quite easy, in case of IntelliJ IDEA it configures the DB Driver automatically.

Comment: I'm using Intellij IDEA and Maven.

Comment: have you tried to change `driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver` to `driverClassName: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver` yet?

Answer (score 0):

I think change name  paplication.yml to application.yml file or introduce the new configuration file to Spring.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).